# Sed sed: -e expression #1, unterminated `s' command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, find

I'm trying to run this sed command using [Renovate](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate), the tool doesn't really matter I think but I'm getting the following error

```
"find . -name release-notes.md -type f -exec sh -c 'sed -i '1s#^#some text#' \"$1\"' sh {} \\;",
```

```
"stderr":"/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string\n",
```

Note that it works fine without the space within the sed expression (some text), meaning that the following works fine

```
"find . -name release-notes.md -type f -exec sh -c 'sed -i '1s#^#sometext#' \"$1\"' sh {} \\;",
```

Thanks

Comment: There may be other issues, but start with replacing `'sed -i '1s#^#some text#'` with `'sed -i \"1s#^#some text#\" ...`.

Answer (score 1):

In the expression `sh -c 'sed -i '1s#^#some text#' \"$1\"'`, the second single quote (the one immediately before "1s") terminates the opening quote and the string `1s#^#some text#` is unquoted.  It's very common to see the script argument to `sed` quoted with single quotes, but it's not at all necessary.  In your case, the 2 simplest solutions are:

```
sh -c 'sed -i 1s#^#some\ text# \"$1\"'
```

and

```
sh -c 'sed -i \"1s#^#some text#\" \"$1\"'
```

But you could simplify everything by avoiding the unnecessary layer of quoting and doing:

```
-exec sed -i -e '1s#^#some text#' {} \;
```

The `-e` isn't strictly necessary, but the non-standard `-i` wants a backup suffix in some versions, and I find it cleaner to explicitly use `-e` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name release-notes.md -type f -exec sed -i '1s/\(some text\)/\"\1\"/' {} \;
```

Using a capture group is often easier then a look behind (or ahead).  The above code worked for me.  Unsure why you calls sh, -exec will use the default shell, and that should work?  unless you have an edge case?

Comment: Thanks but I didn't manage to make it work with Renovate post upgrade script https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#postupgradetasks

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong, but I think this will work.

```
#!/bin/sh -x

find . -name release-notes.md > stack
while read line
do
echo "some text" > newfile
sed -n '2,$p' "${line}" >> newfile
mv -v newfile "${line}"
done < stack
```

I personally dislike using -exec with find.  I feel that find commands are frequently complex enough as it is, without trying to jam everything into a single line.  I frequently see problems with find exec lines which I am able to bypass with methods such as the above.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however, multi line is a hassle with Renovate scripting.